# Adding a global Javascript function, jQuery style?

Tags: javascript

Im looking to send command strings to a flash app, to execute debug commands. Doing this through Firebugs Console/Command-line looks like the simplest way to get this up and running.

At the moment I can log to the firebug console from the flash app by calling out to console using the ExternalInterface. And also send the flash app commands by calling a `command` method added by the `ExternalInterface.addCallback` method. So at the moment in the html file that contains the flash app I have some Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    app = $("#${application}").get(0)
})
```

and at the firebug commandline I can type:

```
app.command('screen.ruler.show')
```

And the flash app receives this. So this is all fine, but I would like to make the `app.command` call as short as possible.

So I would like assign the `app.command` function to a single character function in the style of jqueries $ method. So how would I go about implementing a function $$$?

```
$$$('screen/ruler.show')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$$$ = function( args ) {
    app.command( args );
}
```

Comment: Well that was surprisingly easy :)

Comment: Note, when using var the function wont be global and accessible every where.

Comment: googletorp: It depends on where your `var` is used. In global (window) context it will effectively create "global" function.

Comment: if you don't use `var` inside a function, then it will be declared in global scope.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to make this complex and use closures etc like jQuery, you can just do

```
$$$ = app.command
```

or wrap it inside a function

```
function $$$(arg) {
    app.command(arg);
}
```

or attach it to window like jQuery:

```
window.$$$ = function(arg) {
    app.command(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$(function() {
  $$$("Fred");
});

var app = {
  command: function(arg) {
    alert("hello " + arg);
  }
};

function $$$(arg) {
  app.command(arg);
}
```

This is equivalent:

```
var $$$ = function(arg) {
  app.command(arg);
}
```

to the explicit function declaration.

Javascript has what are called [first class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).